# in Netbeans, how can I show the fully qualified name of a method?

Tags: netbeans

I'm looking at a .java file in NetBeans.

The launch() method is called in this .java file, but its definition is not included in the .java file:

```java
// [many imports here]

public class Jan2018JavaFXToy1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
      // [some code here]
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I want to know where launch() comes from. For example, does it come from the Application class? Or perhaps instead, does it come from a superclass of Application?

In Visual Studio, I believe that either hovering over the method (ie the `launch(args)` source code) or right clicking the method will tell me where it comes from. I don't know how to do this in NetBeans, though.

How do I get NetBeans to tell me where this launch() method comes from?

Comment: You can jump to the source of the function e.g. Ctrl-Click on the method or use Navigate -> Go to source. But I am not aware of any option that does this as a tooltip

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: aha! This solves my problem; thanks for your answer!

Comment: A couple more approaches which do not require displaying the source of the called method: [1] Position the mouse over the called method, right-click and select Call Hierarchy from the popup menu. [2] Position the mouse after the opening (left) bracket of the called method and press CTL/space.